# .net framework application accessing methods and data from Microsoft Dynamics Nav 2013, is it possible?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, navision, dynamics-nav-2013

Has anyone already integrated with NAV2013? I'm in a scenario where Navision doesn't have active webservices, I'm looking to see if I can use the dlls to be able to sell my .net framework application for the nav.
The first time I have contact with this system, I am looking for how to do it correctly, to consult data I will access the database directly, but to place a sales order the correct way would be to access methods from the application itself.
If there is any connector, or available package or documentation, I would appreciate it.

I searched several forums, but I haven't found anything yet.

Comment: The correct way to do it is through the webservices. They ARE the connector you are looking for.